# web banner that needs to be sized 469x60 pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

Designing a web banner that needs to be sized 469x60 pixels. I am using Photoshop and everything looks blurry.

I tried creating it 4x larger and then downsizing but it is still blurry. From what I read, this is a standard web size banner.

How do people create at this small size and keep clarity? I must add that it needs to have animation, so I will export as a GIF.

Comment: Can you upload your banner image? It's to hard to say why it might be blurry without seeing the working file or the exported file. Is everything blurry including the text? Are you viewing the graphic more than 100%?

Comment: Without being able to see it, there's not much to say . . .  Please upload an image. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Some possible facilities to help you with your job:

1. If the size of the banner is 469x60 pixels, the best is working at this size. Photoshop allows to work with more than a window of the same document, while working in the document very zoomed, is possible see the original size in a corner of the screen. **Menu Window** > **Arrange** > **New window for**...
2. For such small sizes files, it's better working in a vector program like Illustrator, and then export, either directly to the .gif file or to a .psd to make the final touches.
3. My working methodology is start the job in Illustrator, copy the most important elements such as graphics, illustrations and texts, and paste them in the original size file in Photoshop as **Smart Objects**. This allows you to edit each object in Illustrator again and update it in Photoshop. I just use Photoshop for effects, mask, colors, and making the animation from the **Timeline Panel**.